# Seeking Tutorials for GML?

Tags: references, gml

Do you know any good tutorials or any resources for learning from the beginning GML?

I am asking  because (later) i would like to learn how to make a application schemas in context of INSPIRE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

I'd suggest starting from http://www.w3.org/Mobile/posdep/GMLIntroduction.html.

If you're planning to work with application schemes in INSPIRE, you'll also need a thorough understanding of XML and XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations).

I think the task doesn't require in-depth understanding of UML. You'll have to be able to read it. Anyway, you can find tons of resources at http://www.uml.org/.

---

- http://code.google.com/p/inspire-foss/wiki/RunDeegree3Demo
- http://inspire-forum.jrc.ec.europa.eu/mod/groups/topicposts.php?topic=26201&group_guid=2288
- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4319

---

You may be able to glean some general info about INSPIRE from some of these links:

- http://www.safe.com/c/inspire/inspire.php
- http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/INSPIRE_ProtectedAreas_Prototype
- http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/INSPIRE_ProtectedAreas_Demo
- http://www.fmeuc.com/archive/fmeuc2009/index.php
  (check out presentation #17)